# How to use xslt to in a hierarchy which a parent <element> may have child <element> which requires different logic

Tags: xml, xslt

So I'm working with an xml document with a structure similar to this

Original XML:

**Normal element**

```
<element name="Name1">
  <document>
    <number>A1</number>
    <reference>B1</reference>
  </document>
</element>
```

**Element which resembles a grouping**
(Added root element for clarity)

```
<root>
<element name="Name2.Group" id="Name2.xxx.Group">
   <element name="Name3">
    <document>
      <number>A2</number>
      <reference>B2</reference>
    </document>
  </element>
  <element name="Name4">
    <document>
      <number>A3</number>
      <reference>B3</reference>
    </document>
  </element>
</element>
</root>
```

What I am trying to get out of this document is something like this

```
<references>
  <reference>
    <original>A1</original>
    <mapping>B1</mapping>
  </reference>
 <reference>
  <group id="Name2.xxx.Group">
    <reference>
        <original>A2</original>
        <mapping>B2</mapping>
      </reference>
      <reference>
        <original>A3</original>
        <mapping>B3</mapping>
      </reference>
    </group>
  </reference>
</references>
```

I am having trouble coming up with a nice way to do this since matching on element seems to match all elements.

So far I have this, but realized it will not work due to parent and child having the same name for an element, but each needing some different logic

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:element name="references">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="element">
    <xsl:element name="reference">
        <xsl:if test="element/document">
            <xsl:element name="original">
                <xsl:value-of select="element/document/number"/>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="mapping">
                <xsl:value-of select="element/document/reference"/>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="id">
                <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The canonical approach to such a task would be to apply the identity transform and make modifications for the nodes that should look different in the output.

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <!-- identity transform - copy everything unless another template fits -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- the document element becomes <references> -->
    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <references>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </references>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- <element> becomes <reference> -->
    <xsl:template match="element">
        <reference>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </reference>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- <element> with group becomes <group> -->
    <xsl:template match="element[contains(@name, '.Group')]">
        <group>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </group>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- we don't want to see element/@name in the output -->
    <xsl:template match="element/@name" /> 

    <!-- <document> is stepped over (just process the children) -->
    <xsl:template match="element/document">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- <number> becomes <original> -->
    <xsl:template match="element/*/number">
        <original>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </original>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- <reference> becomes <mapping> -->
    <xsl:template match="element/*/reference">
        <mapping>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </mapping>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

output, when applied to

```
<x>
    <element name="Name1">
      <document>
        <number>A1</number>
        <reference>B1</reference>
      </document>
    </element>
    <element name="Name2.Group" id="Name2.xxx.Group">
       <element name="Name3">
        <document>
          <number>A2</number>
          <reference>B2</reference>
        </document>
      </element>
      <element name="Name4">
        <document>
          <number>A3</number>
          <reference>B3</reference>
        </document>
      </element>
    </element>    
</x>
```

would be

```
<references>
   <reference>
      <original>A1</original>
      <mapping>B1</mapping>
   </reference>
   <group id="Name2.xxx.Group">
      <reference>
         <original>A2</original>
         <mapping>B2</mapping>
      </reference>
      <reference>
         <original>A3</original>
         <mapping>B3</mapping>
      </reference>
   </group>
</references>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to answer your question exactly, because your second input example is not a well-formed XML (not having a single root element) and your output shows data from both input examples.

The following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <references>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </references>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="element[@id]">
    <group id="{@id}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </group>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="element">
    <reference>
        <original>
            <xsl:value-of select="document/number"/>
        </original>
        <mapping>
            <xsl:value-of select="document/reference"/>     
        </mapping>
    </reference>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to your first input example, will return:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<reference>
   <original>A1</original>
   <mapping>B1</mapping>
</reference>
```

When applied to the following corrected example of your **input**:

```
<root>
 <element name="Name2.Group" id="Name2.xxx.Group">
   <element name="Name3">
    <document>
      <number>A2</number>
      <reference>B2</reference>
    </document>
  </element>
  <element name="Name4">
    <document>
      <number>A3</number>
      <reference>B3</reference>
    </document>
  </element>
</element>
</root>
```

the **result** will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<references>
   <group id="Name2.xxx.Group">
      <reference>
         <original>A2</original>
         <mapping>B2</mapping>
      </reference>
      <reference>
         <original>A3</original>
         <mapping>B3</mapping>
      </reference>
   </group>
</references>
```

Comment: Yeah sorry, I was trying to cut out the specifics of the elements and go with the most basic example of what my issue was. What I meant in the xml example would be to assume both parent elements shown were wrapped in some <root> element, meaning both are in the same document. I will give this a try